# chai expect to.have.all.keys haven't the same behavior than hasOwnProperties

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, chai

can someone explain to me why the two following lines of code don't return the same result?

```
expect(scenar.hasOwnProperty('conditions)).to.true;
expect(scenar).to.have.key('conditions);
```

while using chai@4.2.0, the second line raised an error and not the first one.

Comment: Does your real code closes properly the single quote in both lines?

Comment: for sure ! sorry for the mistake ! I also tried with dubble quotes ... tks

Comment: the second expect returns : `AssertionError: expected { Object (scenarii, opponent, ...)} to have key 'conditions'`

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for `"chai": "^4.2.0"`.

E.g.

```js
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('62430596', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const scenar = { conditions: {} };
    expect(scenar.hasOwnProperty('conditions')).to.true;
    expect(scenar).to.have.key('conditions');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
  62430596
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (22ms)
```